# Do the Snowflake streams have any limitation on amount of data they can process

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am considering using streams and tasks for data transforming and transferring from the CDC table created by the Kafka Snowflake connector (in JSON format) into the fully structured Snowflake tables.

I am wondering is there any limitation on the amount of data the streams can process. I am talking about processing millions of records per day.

Has someone already tested the streams on Big Data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The stream is just an offset pointer.  It doesn't store a copy of the data.  As long as the data is in the base table, it will be in the stream, and have the same performance characteristics as the base table.  There are two additional change tracking columns on the base table, so it would be similar to a 'where' condition on those columns.